# How can I select an element from this drop down menu in Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I've looked through a few solutions to select drop down elements, but none of them are working for me.

This is the html for the dropdown.

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="3" aria-haspopup="true">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">Resolved</div>
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I've tried finding the dropdown by xpath and link text with no success.

EDIT:  Here's the code I'm using

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    driver.get("https://websitename.com/#ticket/123456")
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button"))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button").send_keys("R")
    wait6 = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

The code is supposed to change the selected drop down list element from assigned to resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What xpath did you try?

The simplest I can see is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown')]")
```

However I'm a little confused about your request about 'selecting' as this isn't a `select` element so I'm sorry, I'm not sure I can help there.

Try the given below method with the help of CSS Selector

```
driver.find_element_by_cssselector(".goog-flat-menu-button > .goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown").click();
```

I am sure the above CSS Selector will work.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I want to change the selected element on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the drop down menu (xpath=//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button') first then click the option to select it. 
both operations can be done by click in Selenium IDE. 
if click is not working then try **clickAt** the locators.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't recognize the xpath.  I edited my original question with the code I'm trying to use.